# Django exception line number logging through middleware

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create Django middleware that logs specific information about exceptions that are raised from within views.  I am having trouble getting the line number on which the exception was raised.

Specifically, the end of the traceback shows `File "<string>", line None`.  Where is this `"<string>"` coming from, and why does it show line number `None`?  I get this same result whether I navigate to `/view_raises_exception/` through my tests or through a browser window.  I'm sure I could probably dig through the traceback in my `process_exception()` method to get the line number, but I'm wondering why `exception.lineno` isn't giving me the result I expect.

My setup:

- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (Cloud9)
- Python 3.4.3
- Django 1.9

View:

```
def exception_view(request):
    raise SyntaxError('Custom error message...')
```

Urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^view_raises_exception/', views.exception_view),
    url(r'^view_raises_no_exceptions/', views.no_exception_view),
]
```

Middleware file:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

class ExceptionLoggingMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        name = type(exception).__name__
        message = str(exception)
        line_no = exception.lineno
        print('***INSIDE PROCESS_EXCEPTIONS***')
        print('Name:', name)
        print('Message:', message)
        print('Line Number:', line_no)
        # return HttpResponse('Exception handled.')
```

Server log:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 09, 2016 - 22:58:40
Django version 1.9, using settings 'middlewares_library.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8080/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
***INSIDE PROCESS_EXCEPTIONS***
Name: SyntaxError
Message: Custom error message...
Line Number: None
Internal Server Error: /view_raises_exception/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/middlewares_library/library/views.py", line 6, in exception_view
    raise SyntaxError('Custom error message...')
  File "<string>", line None
SyntaxError: Custom error message...
[09/Sep/2016 22:58:43] "GET /view_raises_exception/ HTTP/1.1" 500 68472
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe not want you need, but you can use `import traceback; print traceback.format_exc(exception)` and it will print the full stack trace with the line number.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm going to end up using `traceback.extract_stack()` from that module, and just getting the line number by position in the stack relative to the end. I'm just not entirely comfortable doing that, not knowing what that last stack trace entry is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this recently writing [ExceptBot](http://exceptbot.com). That links to the source repo.

The relevant code is:

```py
import traceback


class ExceptBotMiddleware:

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        # Get the current stack trace
        current_traceback = traceback.extract_stack()
        stack = current_traceback[-1]
        # getting the line number
        line_number = stack.lineno
```